# Stacked Bar Chart: Week vs Week

Tags: highcharts

I'm struggling with creating a stacked bar chart which basically compares week to week performance. I have the overall numbers charted fine:

[image]

I'm now being tasked with showing how individual proposals contribute to the overall number.  Each week can have any number of proposals or none at all.

The desired outcome would look something like:

[image]

I'm building the series by week.  So for "This Week" I would know {10, 30, 15, 4, 20, 10}  "Last Week" I would know {20, 25}, "Two weeks ago" I would know {17, 3, 2, 2} etc.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you any jsfiddle with your current work to share with us please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use stacking option and divide data into series, for example:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'normal'
  }
},
series: [{
  data: [2, 4, 0, 1, 4, 8]
}, {
  data: [2, 4, 5, 0, 4, 8]
}, {
  data: [2, 4, 0, 1, 4, 8]
}, {
  data: [2, 4, 5, 1, 4, 8]
}],
xAxis: {
  categories: [...]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4894/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.stacking